# C# WPF TreeViewItem Как убрать отступ?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как убрать отступ у дочерних елементов TreeViewItem?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Шаблон элемента смотрели?

Comment: А какая у вас конечная задача? Судя по вашим вопросам вы хотите сделать List с возможностью сворачивания элементов. Так может вам использовать просто Expander?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, не нашел

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, по факту мне нужен list expander'ов, т.е мне нужно задать ItemsSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Щелкните по `TreeView` в дизайнере правой кнопкой и выберите <kbd>Edit Additional Templates</kbd>><kbd>Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)</kbd>><kbd>Edit a Copy...</kbd> введите имя стиля и нажмите <kbd>OK</kbd>

Ищем в полученных ресурсах стиль для `TreeViewItem` (`<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">`) и в нем шаблон (`<Setter Property="Template">`), видим, что в шаблоне `Grid` с несколькими колонками и `ItemsPresenter` (который предназначен для вывода дочерних элементов) лежит во второй-третьей колонках:

```
<ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

меняем:

```
<ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

По сути здесь просто нужен вложенный ItemsControl или что то на его основе.

К примеру используем такой вид:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderThickness="0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`TestItems` - это простая коллекция `ObservableCollection<Test>`.
`Test` - класс, который содержит свойство с именем и некий внутренний массив:

```
class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Результат получим такой:

[image: Result]

Конечно вы можете тут настроит все как вам нужно. К примеру если хотите выделение, то можно `ItemsControl` переделать на `ListBox` со своим стилем или чем то еще.

---

Также тут можно пойти по пути группировки, то есть наши элементы к примеру будут такого вида:

```
class Test
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда View с группировкой будет следующий:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TestGroups" Source="{Binding TestItems}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestGroups}}">
        <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Результат получим такой:

[image: Result 2]

В общем все зависит от конечного результата, я показал только как можно поступить. Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

Заслуга идеи @EvgeniyZ: нужно выбирать более подходящий контрол

```
<ListBox ItemsSouce="{Binding }">
    <ListBox.ItemsTemplate>
        <DataTempalte>
            <Expander/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: А как в ListBox Expander засунуть дочерние елементы?

Comment: @MikeWaters в Expander если нужны дочерние элементы еще один ListBox